# Socket Error The requested address is not valid in its context

Tags: c#, sockets, multicast

While Trying to Set the SocketOption using :

```
    listener.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP,
   SocketOptionName.AddMembership, new MulticastOption(ipAddress));
```

I am getting the following exception ;

> The requested address is not valid in its context

My listmer is:

```
  Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
      SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
```

and Ip is 3.212.x.x

Is this a problem because of IP ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is in this statement:

```
listener.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP,
   SocketOptionName.AddMembership, new MulticastOption(ipAddress));
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b02d330e(v=vs.110).aspx) outline this constructor as :

```
public MulticastOption(
    IPAddress group
)
```

So the MulticastOption looks for a Group to broadcast but I had passed localIP and that was the problem.

I instead I updated my Code:

```
 IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("224.5.6.7");



Socket _socketServer = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram,
            ProtocolType.Udp);
        _socketServer.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP,


SocketOptionName.AddMembership, new MulticastOption(ip));
            _socketServer.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, 
  SocketOptionName.MulticastTimeToLive, 1);
```